# Python: Deleting Customer Accounts from Bank System

Tags: python

Already asked this question and I had a very negative response so I'll forewarn you that I am *extremely* new to Python and programming as a whole so I don't quite understand most terminology but I'll try anyway

I have to insert a method of deleting a customer account from the `customers_list`, both stored within `bank_system`

I shall put a code sample of `bank_system` here. 
The `customers_list` is found at the top and the method to delete accounts is found near the bottom.

```
from customer import Customer
from admin import Admin
from account import Account




class BankSystem(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.customers_list = []
        self.admins_list = []
        self.load_bank_data()

    def load_bank_data(self):
        #CUSTOMER LIST
        customer_1 = Customer("Adam", "1234", ["14", "Wilcot Street", "Bath", "B5 5RT"])
        account_no = 1234
        account_1 = Account(5000.00, account_no)
        customer_1.open_account(account_1)
        self.customers_list.append(customer_1)

        customer_2 = Customer("David", "password", ["60", "Holborn Via-duct", "London", "EC1A 2FD"])
        account_no+=1
        account_2 = Account(3200.00, account_no)
        customer_2.open_account(account_2)
        self.customers_list.append(customer_2)

        customer_3 = Customer("Alice", "MoonLight", ["5", "Cardigan Street", "Birmingham", "B4 7BD"])
        account_no+=1
        account_3 = Account(18000.00, account_no)
        customer_3.open_account(account_3)
        self.customers_list.append(customer_3)

        customer_4 = Customer("Ali", "150A", ["44", "Churchill Way West", "Basingstoke", "RG21 6YR"])
        account_no+=1
        account_4 = Account(18000.00, account_no)
        customer_4.open_account(account_4)
        self.customers_list.append(customer_4)

        customer_5 = Customer("Thomas", "15A", ["4", "Churchill West", "Stoke", "ST21 6YR"])
        account_no+=1
        account_5 = Account(0, account_no)
        customer_5.open_account(account_5)
        self.customers_list.append(customer_5)

        #ADMIN LIST
        admin_1 = Admin("Julian", "1441", True, ["12", "London Road", "Birmingham", "B95 7TT"])
        self.admins_list.append(admin_1)

        admin_2 = Admin("Eva", "2222", False, ["47", "Mars Street", "Newcastle", "NE12 6TZ"])
        self.admins_list.append(admin_2)

    def customer_login(self, name, password):
        #step A.1 CUSTOMER LOGIN
        found_customer = self.search_customers_by_name(name)
        if found_customer == None:
            return("\n The customer you are looking for has not been found!\n")
        else:
            if (found_customer.check_password(password) == True):
                self.run_customer_options(found_customer)
            else:
                return("You have input an incorrect password")


    def admin_login(self, name, password):
        #step A.3 ADMIN LOGIN
        found_admin = self.search_admin_by_name(name)
        if found_admin == None:
            return("\n The administrator you are looking for has not been found!\n")
        else:
            if (found_admin.check_password(password) == True):
                self.run_admin_options(found_admin)
            else:
                return("You have input an incorrect password")


    def search_customers_by_name(self, customer_name):
        #step A.2 SEARCHING FOR CUSTOMERS
        found_customer = None
        for a in self.customers_list:
            name = a.get_name()
            if name == customer_name:
                found_customer = a
            if found_customer == None:
                print("\n The customer %s doesn't exist! Please try again...\n" %customer_name)
            else:
                return found_customer


    def main_menu(self):
        #MAIN MENU OPTIONS
        print()
        print()
        print ("-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-")
        print()
        print ("Welcome to the Python Bank System")
        print()
        print ("-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-")
        print ("1) Admin login")
        print ("2) Customer login")
        print ("3) Quit the Python Bank System")
        print (" ")
        option = int(input("Choose your option: "))
        return option

    def run_main_option(self):
        loop = 1
        while loop == 1:
            choice = self.main_menu()
            if choice == 1:
                #ADMIN LOGIN
                name = input ("\n Please input admin name: ")
                password = input ("\n Please input admin password: ")
                msg = self.admin_login(name, password)
                print(msg)
            elif choice == 2:
                #CUSTOMER LOGIN
                name = input ("\n Please input customer name: ")
                password = input ("\n Please input customer password: ")
                msg = self.customer_login(name, password)
                print(msg)
            elif choice == 3:
                loop = 0
        print ("Thank you for stopping by the bank!")


    def trasnfer_money(self, sender_account, receiver_name, receiver_account_no, amount):
        #TRANSFERRING MONEY TO OTHER ACCOUNTS
        pass


    def customer_menu(self, customer_name):
        #CUSTOMER SPECIFIC MENU
         print (" ")
         print ("Welcome %s : Your transaction options are:" %customer_name)
         print ("-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-")
         print ("1) Transfer money")
         print ("2) Other account operations")
         print ("3) profile settings")
         print ("4) Sign out")
         print (" ")
         option = int(input ("Choose your option: "))
         return option


    def run_customer_options(self, customer):
        #CUSTOMER OPTIONS            
        account = customer.get_account()            
        loop = 1
        while loop == 1:
            choice = self.customer_menu(customer.get_name())
            if choice == 1:
                pass
            elif choice == 2:
                account.run_account_options()
            elif choice == 3:
                customer.run_profile_options()
            elif choice == 4:
                loop = 0
        print ("Exit account operations")



    def search_admin_by_name(self, name):
        #step A.4 SEARCHING FOR ADMINS
        found_admin = None
        admin_name = name
        for a in self.admins_list:
            name = a.get_name()
            if name == admin_name:
                found_admin = a
            if found_admin == None:
                print("\n The administrator %s doesn't exist! Please try again...\n" %admin_name)
            else:
                return found_admin


    def admin_menu(self, admin_name):
        #ADMINISTRATOR SPECIFIC MENU
        print (" ")
        print ("Welcome Admin %s : Available options are:" %admin_name)
        print ("-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-")
        print ("1) Transfer money")
        print ("2) Customer account operations")
        print ("3) Customer profile settings")
        print ("4) Admin profile settings")
        print ("5) Delete customer")
        print ("6) Print all customers detail")
        print ("7) Sign out")
        print (" ")
        option = int(input ("Choose your option: "))
        return option


    def run_admin_options(self, admin):
        #ADMINISTRATOR OPTIONS
        loop = 1
        while loop == 1:
            choice = self.admin_menu(admin.get_name())
            if choice == 1:
                pass
            elif choice == 2:
                #step A.5 SEARCHING FOR CUSTOMERS
                customer_name = input("\n Please input customer name :\n")
                customer = self.search_customers_by_name(customer_name)
                if customer != None:
                    account = customer.get_account()
                    if account != None:
                        account.run_account_options()
            elif choice == 3:
                #step A.6 UPDATING CUSTOMER NAME
                customer_name = input("\n Please input customer name :\n")
                customer = self.search_customers_by_name(customer_name)
                if customer != None:
                    customer.run_profile_options()
            elif choice == 4:
                #step A.7 UPDATING ADMIN NAME (SELF ONLY)
                admin.run_profile_options()
            elif choice == 5:
                #step A.8 DELETING CUSTOMER
                if admin.has_full_admin_right() == True:
                    name = input("\n Please input customer name you want to delete :\n")
                    customer_account = self.search_customers_by_name(name)
                    if customer_account !=None:
                        print ("The customer does not exist")
                    else: self.customers_list.remove(name)       
                else:
                    print("\n Only administrators with full admin rights can remove a customer from the bank system!\n")
            elif choice == 6:
                #step A.9 PRINTING ALL CUSTOMER DETAILS
                self.print_all_accounts_details()
            elif choice == 7:
                loop = 0
        print ("Exit account operations")


    def print_all_accounts_details(self):
            # list related operation - move to main.py
            i = 0
            for c in self.customers_list:
                i+=1
                print('\n %d. ' %i, end = ' ')
                c.print_details()
                print("------------------------")

app = BankSystem()
app.run_main_option()
```

With the code I have currently, Python shell returns this:

```
Please input customer name you want to delete :
Adam
The customer does not exist

Welcome Admin Julian : Available options are:
-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-
1) Transfer money
2) Customer account operations
3) Customer profile settings
4) Admin profile settings
5) Delete customer
6) Print all customers detail
7) Sign out

Choose your option:
```

As you can see, when I enter `'Adam'` Python simply returns '`The customer does not exist'`

Considering this and then looking back through my code and to the method that would delete the account, this would mean that the `search_customers_by_name` method does not work correctly. However all other options that use this method work perfectly.

What can I do to correct this?

Comment: When deleting an account, after getting the customer with `search_customers_by_name` you check if the return value exists (`customer_account != None`) and print that it does not exist if it does exist.

Comment: In addition to what @Tulir pointed out, the way your code is written `if found_customer == None:` within `search_customers_by_name` is executed on every iteration of the loop. Meaning that the method will actually only ever consider the very first customer in the list

Answer (score 0):

In the deletion option, you are displaying the message that the customer does not exist if there is a customer found (if customer_account **!=** None:). By reversing this (if customer_account **==** None:) it will alert you if it did not found the customer, which I think is the desired behavior. The corrected code is below:

```
elif choice == 5:
                #step A.8 DELETING CUSTOMER
                if admin.has_full_admin_right() == True:
                    name = input("\n Please input customer name you want to delete :\n")
                    customer_account = self.search_customers_by_name(name)
                    if customer_account == None:
                        print ("The customer does not exist")
                    else: self.customers_list.remove(name)       
                else:
                    print("\n Only administrators with full admin rights can remove a customer from the bank system!\n")
```

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\University\Term 1 Assessment\Banking System submission\test30112017\bank_system.py", line 247, in <module>
    app.run_main_option()
  File "D:\University\Term 1 Assessment\Banking System submission\test30112017\bank_system.py", line 114, in run_main_option
    msg = self.admin_login(name, password)`

Comment: `File "D:\University\Term 1 Assessment\Banking System submission\test30112017\bank_system.py", line 72, in admin_login
    self.run_admin_options(found_admin)
  File "D:\University\Term 1 Assessment\Banking System submission\test30112017\bank_system.py", line 226, in run_admin_options
    else: self.customers_list.remove(name)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`

Comment: That would indicate that it does find something just not what is recognized in the list. In the delete user code, comment out the if customer_account all the way to print("\n") lines and print the output you get from the search to see what is being returned. It may be possible that what is being returned is not suitable for a list.remove